# C# Google API Authentication

Tags: c#, google-api

I am having an issue where I am able to authenticate when running as a Console Application.  But when I make it a Windows Service and install it, I am unable to authenticate.  I have used log debug statements to isolate the issue.

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets {
            ClientId = "myClientId",
            ClientSecret = "myClientSecret"
        },
        new[] {
            CalendarService.Scope.Calendar
        },
        "myProjectName",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore("myProjectName")
).Result;
```

The issue is with the above statement.  This is surrounded by a try/catch, but no Exception is thrown.  There is a log statement immediately after this, but it is never executed.  My best guess is that the issue is with the FileDataStore.  By default Google stores this is %AppData% which my program can find when I run it manually, but when it is a web service I am forced to give it an account type like Local System or Local Service I need to set it as User I think.  My guess is that this prevents it from finding the file in %AppData%.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to help the Windows Service find %AppData%?  Or is a Windows Service a bad approach in this situation?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this approach is only valid if you have a UI, because it will launch a browser to ask for authentication. For a service you have to ask for another kind of key that implies installing a certificate in the server. It is explained in [OAuth2ServiceAccount](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).